# get api request with increment number on last parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to access data using pagination and lazy loading. Buts its working only only for first request.Last parameter incement at the end of the page is not working.  http://features.domain_server.com/mobileapi/eggsrate/1/0. I am trying to change last parameter at the end of the page.  http://features.domain_server.com/mobileapi/eggsrate/1/1 and when second request complete then http://features.domain_server.com/mobileapi/eggsrate/1/2 then http://features.domain_server.com/mobileapi/eggsrate/1/3   . I have try with increment method but its not working.

```js
new Vue({

  el: "#app",
  data: {
    posts: [],
    limit: 8,
    busy: false
  },
  methods: {
    loadMore() {


      console.log("Adding 8 more data results");
      this.busy = true;
      axios.get("http://features.domain_server.com/mobileapi/eggsrate/1/0").then(response => {
        const append = response.data.slice(
          this.posts.length,
          this.posts.length + this.limit
        );
        this.posts = this.posts.concat(append);
        this.busy = false;
      });

    },

  },
  created() {
    this.loadMore();
  }
});
AOS.init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Egg Rates</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css'>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<section class="section">
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <div v-infinite-scroll="loadMore" infinite-scroll-disabled="busy" infinite-scroll-distance="limit">
        <li v-for="post in posts" style="margin-bottom: 2rem;" data-aos="slide-up" data-aos-offset="100" data-aos-easing="ease-out-back">
          <div class="card">
            <header class="card-header">
              <p class="card-header-title">
                {{post.id}}
              </p>
            </header>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="content">
                <p>{{post.name}}</p>
                <p>{{post.cities}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.8/vue.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vue-infinite-scroll@2.0.2/vue-infinite-scroll.js'></script>
<script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you've hardcoded `http://features.domain_server.com/mobileapi/eggsrate/1/0` - how do you expect to get `http://features.domain_server.com/mobileapi/eggsrate/2`?

Comment: The use of `response.data.slice` implies that this API does not actually provide pagination or if it does, you're messing with the number of records on the client-side which seems odd

Comment: also, your console.log says *Adding 10 more data results* ... your code however has limit of 8 ...

Comment: @Phil I want only last number increment which one has 0 value. Api have the limit of r row after change it 1/2 api request showing 9 to 18 record and after 1/3 api json data showing 19 to 27.

Comment: @JaromandaX  1 is fix value and i want increment only for last digit

Comment: @Phil Api Providing pagination i have tested its on postman.

Comment: @JaromandaX You can consider its only http://features.domain_server.com/mobileapi/eggsrate/1/0 . 1 is fix value and i want increment only for last 0 parameter

Comment: Yes its 1/0 , 1/2 , 1/3 , 1/4 , 1/5. @Phil 1 does not matter its  fix my api pagination change data according to last value

Comment: sure, you want to do that, and you say you've `try with increment method` - but your code shows no such attempt

Answer (score 0):

All other considerations aside, you just need to keep track of the current page and increment it when *loading more*.

```js
data: () => ({
  posts: [],
  limit: 8,
  busy: false,
  page: 0 //  added this
}),
```

and in `loadMore()`

```js
axios.get(`http://features.domain_server.com/mobileapi/eggsrate/1/${this.page++}`)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But its not working showing same output after added this.page++ console.log showing with infinite loop